# Python, Beautiful Soup list works manually, but not with a for loop ?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem with my code, using beautiful soup. I am getting this error message on this code below, when I manually put the number into the list indices(Ex: c = b[11]), it worked, but when I attach the code to a for loop, and use c = b[i] the code doesn't work. There are 220 links in "b", **I want every 11th link**. When I manually put in **c = b[0]**(<--the first link on the page), and **c = b[209]**(<--the last/20th link on the page), they both work, is just when I put it under a for loop, it does not work

```
a = urlopen(url) # Opens the page that I want

for i in range(0, 220, 11): # Once the url is open, gets the 20 links on the page
        bsobj = BeautifulSoup(a, "lxml")
        b = bsobj.findAll("td", height="10") #len of b is 220
        c = b[i] #len is 1
        d = c.findAll("a")
        e = d[0].attrs["href"]
        f = e[13:18]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Perl\Documents\Finviz.py", line 48, in <module>
    c = b[i] #len is 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Move the `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(a, "lxml")` out of the loop.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: How does moving this line outside help the index error? May be I am missing something. `bsobj` stays the same either we read it every time or just once, right?

Comment: @Bazingaa Since `a` is an iterator, `bsobj` will be an empty HTML document in every iteration of the loop except the first one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Aran-Fey, what you said got rid of the error message, but now the code is only, printing out the last like that I need instead of all 20. This is the new code :for i in range(0,220,11), it is only giving me the last link(209), instead of all 20. It is not cycling through ALL 20 links in the range

Comment: Edit, I got it, the problem was that I had the print(), outside of the loop, problem, solved, thanks @Aran-Fey.. How do I give points here, I'm new. This is only the 2nd question that I have asked, and the 1st to get a reply/solution, Thanks....

Comment: You can't award me points unless I post an answer. I'm not planning on doing that though. You can wait for someone else to post an answer, or post an answer yourself, or just delete the question.